# Does my breast size decrease permanently after weight loss?

Tags: weight-loss, breast

I have been running for a while now and dieting, and I've lost a couple of pounds of weight. I'm now 130 lbs and 5 foot 11, and 25 years old. As a result, my breast size has also decreased.

I've heard that you lose more of your breast fat if you're on a calorie deficit, than what you gain if you're on a calorie surplus.

In other words, I've heard that if you lose 5 pounds, and then gain 5 pounds, you will have relatively less fat in your breasts in the end than before you lost the 5 pounds, and relatively more in your belly.

Is this true? is there scientific evidence for this, or for it being false?

Comment: Good question, I'm interested in seeing if someone finds data on this.  But I have to say that from a health perspective, I'm not sure why you've dieted, as your BMI is underweight.  Women who are underweight put themselves at higher risk for poor bone mineral density and pathological fractures, endocrine dysfunction, infertility, anemia, hair loss, weakened immunity... Running is a healthy activity, but eating enough (nutrient-dense foods) to maintain normal weight is very important to your overall health. https://familydoctor.org/healthy-ways-to-gain-weight-if-youre-underweight/